# Any Scala SDK or interface for AWS?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

Does anyone know of a Scala SDK for Amazon Web Services? I am particularly interested in the EMR jobs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at AWScala (it's a simple wrapper on top of AWS SDK for Java):

https://github.com/seratch/AWScala

[UPDATE from 04/07/2015]: Another very promising library from @dwhjames:

Asynchronous Scala Clients for Amazon Web Services 
https://dwhjames.github.io/aws-wrap/

Comment: this looks impressive. Thanks @Alex

Comment: A bit of a drawback is that AWScala draws in all of `aws-java-sdk` (30 MB lib), even if you only need, say, Amazon S3 and `aws-java-sdk-s3` dependency would suffice (2.7 + 2.4 MB with `aws-java-sdk-core`).

Comment: @jonik seems this has been addressed and you can now only add the S3 dependency if that's all you need

Answer (score 12):

You could use the standard Java SDK directly without any problems from Scala, however I'm not aware of any Scala specific SDKs.

Comment: Moreover, I don't see why Java SDK may be not suitable for Scala

Comment: @yegor256 It's badly suitable for Scala because it's blocking by default and its `async` set of classes uses ancient and useless Java `Future` that doesn't have completion callback.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian's [aws-scala](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-scala) is quite good.

p.s. Currently the library has basic support for S3, DynamoDB, CloudFormation and SQS

Comment: What makes me uneasy about using this one is that the issue tracker is private. So we cannot see the existing bugs or even file bugs.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than others. Could really use some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just regular AWS Java SDK in scala. For example:

Add the following to `build.sbt` if you use SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.12.1"
```

then:

```
package example

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;

// for conversions from java collections to scala collections
// e.g. java.util.List to scala List
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

object Hello extends  App {

  // create s3 client
  val s3:AmazonS3  = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2).build();

  // get bucket list
  val buckets:List[Bucket]  = s3.listBuckets().asScala.toList          

  // print bucket names
  buckets.foreach(b => println(b.getName()))
}
```