# Extract AWS Glue credentials from created glue client Scala

Tags: java, scala, connection, aws-glue, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am attempting to extract emmbedded connection credentials in reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63385665/extract-embedded-aws-glue-connection-credentials-using-scala).
But I get the following error.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  //import everything from the package    
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window => W} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser 

import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model._

import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{AWSGlue, AWSGlueClient}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.{mapAsJavaMapConverter, seqAsJavaListConverter}
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemaker.sparksdk.IAMRole

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)

val region = Regions.fromName("us-east-1")

// Function to create AWS glue client
def glueClient(region: Regions):
AWSGlue = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion(region).build()

val glue = glueClient(region =region)

glue.getConnection("{Name: name-of-embedded-connection,HidePassword: False}")
```

> > An error was encountered: :71: error: type mismatch;  found   : String("{Name: preprod-samtec-redw,HidePassword: False}")  required:
> > com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetConnectionRequest
> > glue.getConnection("{Name: name-of-embedded-connection,HidePassword: False}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you need to provide a `GetConnectionRequest` object to the `getConnection`method, something like:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  //import everything from the package    
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window => W} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser 

import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model._

import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{AWSGlue, AWSGlueClient}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.{mapAsJavaMapConverter, seqAsJavaListConverter}
import com.amazonaws.services.sagemaker.sparksdk.IAMRole

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)

val region = Regions.fromName("us-east-1")

// Function to create AWS glue client
def glueClient(region: Regions):
AWSGlue = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion(region).build()

val glue = glueClient(region =region)

val getConnectionRequest: GetConnectionRequest = new GetConnectionRequest()
  .withName("name-of-embedded-connection")
  .withHidePassword(false)

val getConnectionResult: GetConnectionResult =  glue.getConnection(getConnectionRequest)

val connection: Connection = getConnectionResult.getConnection()

val connectionProperties = connection.getConnectionProperties()

// Now you can extract as many properties as you need (see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2d73c9847a327eea2f673a4cd2b3449e433649e5/aws-java-sdk-glue/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/glue/model/Connection.java#L687)
// For instance, the username or password
val username = connectionProperties.get("USERNAME")
val password = connectionProperties.get("PASSWORD")
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'new' found.
val connectionRequest: new GetConnectionRequest()
                       ^ `

Comment: Sorry Jay, I forgot to include the type of the variable. Can you try now? You can also try just ```val connectionRequest = new GetConnectionRequest()
  .withName("name-of-embedded-connection")
  .withHidePassword(false)```

Comment: Nice Jay!! I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer with, I think, the code needed to replicate your Python code (please note that I am editing it manually, hope I haven't made any mistakes)

Comment: Thank you, and do not worry Jay, I am fluent in Python. Yes, I think that you only need to obtain the value like this ```val username = connectionProperties.get("USERNAME")```. I do not understand what you mean with JSON: is it related with the way you process the result in python? In Java/Scala, you have a ```Map```, analogous to a Python dictionary, and you can get the value that correspond to a certain key passing it as an argument of the ```get``` method. In fact, in your code, you are processing a Python dictionary, aren't you?

Comment: I basically just need it to extract the connection so that I dont have to explicitly pass credentials. I reran your code and get this error `<console>:2: error: ';' expected but ',' found.
val connectionProperties: java.util.Map<String, String> = connection.getConnectionProperties()
                                              ^` any ideas?

Comment: Please, just remove the type: ```val connectionProperties = connection.getConnectionProperties()``` - sorry, Java bad habits!! Please, can you see if it works?

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks so much for all your help and prompt responses.

Comment: You are welcome Jay. I am really glad to know that it helps.